# Map between $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$

Tags: group-theory

I was reading "Skyrmions, a Theory of Nuclei" by Manton. Writing about the properties of $SU(2)$ he said that the map
$$
M_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} Tr(\tau_i U \tau_j U^{-1})
$$
is a map between $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$ ($M_{ij}$ is the $ij$ element of a $SO(3)$ matrix), where $U \in SU(2)$ and $\tau_i$ is a Pauli matrix.

Is there a way to prove this easily? I was not able to do it.

Comment: What is your question? Whether $(M_{ij}) \in SO(3)$?

Comment: Yes, than you, why $M \in SO(3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all due respect to Manton, if that is indeed what he does, defining the map from $\mathrm{SU}_2$ to $\mathrm{SO}_3$ by this formula is a god-awful way to describe the map!

Any element of $\mathrm{U}_2$ is a matrix of the form
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} z_1 & -\lambda\bar{w_1}\\ w_1 & \lambda\bar{z_1} \end{array}\right)
$$
where $|z_1|^2+|w_1|^2=1=|\lambda|^2$. Indeed the columns of any element of $\mathrm{U}_2$ must be an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb C^2$, and hence the first column of $A$ must have the form $(z_1,w_1)^{\intercal}$ where $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1$, and the second column must lie on the line orthogonal to $\mathbb C.(z_1,w_1)^\intercal$, which is just $\mathbb C.(-\bar{w_1},\bar{z_1})^{\intercal}$. Now if the second column is to have norm $1$, it follows that the scalar multiple $\lambda$ of $(\bar{w_1},\bar{z_1})^{\intercal}$ must be a complex number $\lambda$ of norm $1$. It is thus clear that $A \in \mathrm{SU}_2$ if and only if $\lambda=1$. Thus we see that
$$
\mathrm{SU}_2 = \left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc} z_1 & -\bar{w_1} \\ w_1 & \bar{z}_1\end{array}\right): z_1,w_1 \in \mathbb C, |z_1|^2+|w_1|^2=1 \right\}
$$
It is thus evident that $\mathrm{SU}_2$ is diffeomorphic to $S^3$ the $3$-sphere in $\mathbb R^4$, and so in particular *it is simply-connected*.

To see the map to $\mathrm{SO}_3$, first note that $\langle A,B \rangle = \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{tr}(A^*B)$ is an Hermitian inner product on $\mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb C)$ (conjugate linear in the first factor and linear in the second) where we write $A^*$ for $\bar{A}^t$, the conjugate-transpose map. Now if $g \in \mathrm{U}_2$, $(gAg^{-1})^* = (gAg^*)^* = gA^*g^*$, so that conjugation by $g$ commutes with taking conjugate-transpose. It follows that if $g \in \mathrm{U}_2$ and $A,B \in \mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb C)$ then
$$
\langle gAg^{-1},gBg^{-1}\rangle =\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(gA^*g^*.gBg^*) = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(gA^*Bg^*) = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(A^*B) = \langle A,B\rangle
$$
Thus if we write $c\colon \mathrm{GL}_2\to \mathrm{GL}(\mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb C))$ for the map given by $c(g)(X) = gXg^{-1}$, then $c$ restricts to a map $\mathrm{U}_2 \to \mathrm{U}(\mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb C))$.

Let $\mathfrak a_2 = \{A \in \mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb C): A-A^*=0\}$ and $\mathfrak u_2 = \{A \in \mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb C): A+A^*=0\}$ be the subspaces of Hermitian and skew-Hermitian matrices respectively. Since for $g \in \mathrm{U}_2$ we have seen that $c(g)$ commutes with taking conjugate-transpose, the subspaces $\mathfrak a_2$ and $\mathfrak u_2$ are preserved by the action of $\mathrm{U}_2$ given by conjugation. Since conjugation moreover preserves trace, it follows that $\mathrm{U}_2$ acts on the subspace $\mathfrak{sa}_2 = \{X \in \mathfrak{a}_2: \mathrm{tr}(X)=0\}$. Now the inner product $\langle A,B \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(A^*B)$ restricts to a real positive-definite symmetric bilinear form on $\mathfrak{sa}_2$ -- indeed if we let
$$
\tau_1 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array}\right),
\tau_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & i \\ -i & 0 \end{array}\right),
\tau_3 = \left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right),
$$
then $\{\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathfrak{sa}_3$. It follows that the action of $\mathrm{U}_2$ on $\mathfrak {sa}_2$ given by $c(g)(X) = gXg^*$ (for $g \in \mathrm{U}_2, X \in \mathfrak{sa}_2$) induces a homomorphism $\pi \colon \mathrm{SU}_2 \to \mathrm{O}_3$, and since $\mathrm{SU}_2$ is connected, we must in fact have $\pi \colon \mathrm{SU}_2 \to \mathrm{SO}_3$. Since $\mathrm{SU}_2$ is compact and $\pi$ is clearly continuous, its image is a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}_3$, and hence as both groups are $3$-dimensional, $\pi$ is surjective. Its kernel clearly contains $\{\pm I\}$, and it is not hard to check using the basis $\{\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3\}$ that $\{\pm I \}$ is in fact the entire kernel.

To see that this is indeed Manton's map, note that the matrix of $c(g)$ with respect to that basis $B=\{\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3\}$ is given by $(a_{ij})$ where  $c(g)(\tau_j) = \sum_{i=1}^3 a_{ij} \tau_i$, and then since $B$ is an orthonormal basis, it follows that $a_{ij} = \langle \tau_i,c(g)(\tau_j)\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}(\tau_ig\tau_j g^{-1})$.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a map $2\rightarrow1$ that associates a couple of matrices $U,-U \in \operatorname{SU}(2)$ to a $M\in \operatorname{SO}(3)$. This mapping is a homomorphism between the two groups because the composition rule is preserved, i.e. $U_1*_IU_2=M_1*_{II}M_2$, where $*_I$ is the composition rule in $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ and $*_{II}$ is the composition rule in $\operatorname{SO}(3)$.
It's known that is possible to map a generic $3-$vector into a Hermitian traceless matrix 2x2 using Pauli matrices $$\mathbf{v}=(x,y,z)\longrightarrow V=x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y+z\sigma_z=\begin{pmatrix} z & x-iy \\\ x+iy & -z\end{pmatrix}=V^\dagger \in \mathcal{H}^{2x2}_{\text{traceless}}$$
Note also that the generic Hermitian traceless matrix $V$ transforms as $$-H=\begin{pmatrix} -\xi_1\xi_2 & \xi_1^2 \\\ -\xi_2^2 & \xi_1\xi_2\end{pmatrix}$$ where the coefficients $\xi_1,\xi_2 $ can be identified as the components of $\xi=\begin{pmatrix} \xi_1  \\\ \xi_2 \end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{C}^2$.

Then, if one identifies $U=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\\ -b^* & a^*\end{pmatrix}\in \operatorname{SU}(2)$ (with the condition $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$) and $M\in SO(3)$ the transformation laws are
$$\xi'=U\xi\longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} \xi_1'  \\\ \xi_2' \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\\ -b^* & a^*\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \xi_1  \\\ \xi_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$V'=UVU^{-1}=UVU^\dagger$$
$$\mathbf{v'}=M\mathbf{v}$$
Setting equal the coefficients of $V$ and $-H$, i.e.
$$\begin{cases}
x+iy=+\xi_2^2 \\\
x-iy=-\xi_1^2 \\\
z=\xi_1\xi_2
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
x=\frac{1}{2}(\xi_2^2-\xi_1^2) \\\
y=\frac{1}{2i}(\xi_2^2+\xi_1^2) \\\
z=\xi_1\xi_2
\end{cases}$$

Starting from the transformation law
$$UHU^\dagger=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\\ -b^* & a^*\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \xi_1\xi_2 & -\xi_1^2\\\ \xi_2^2 & \xi_1\xi_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a^* & -b\\\ b^* & a \end{pmatrix}$$

In the end, one gets the component of the transformed $3-$vector under $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ from which is easy to deduce the $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ matrix associated to the $2$ matrices of  $\operatorname{SU}(2)$
$$\begin{cases}
x'=\frac{1}{2}[ x(a^2+{a^*}^2-b^2-{b^*}^2)-iy(a^2-{a^*}^2+b^2-{b^*}^2)-2z(ab+a^*b^*) ] \\\
y'=\frac{1}{2}[ ix(a^2-{a^*}^2-b^2+{b^*}^2)+y(a^2+{a^*}^2+b^2+{b^*}^2)-2iz(ab-a^*b^*) ] \\\
z'=x(ab^*+a^*b)+iy(a^*b-ab^*)+z(|a|^2-|b|^2)
\end{cases}$$

It's also evident that is a double cover: from a matricial perspective $V'$ doesn't see the difference between $U$ and $-U$ because in the transformation law $U$ appears twice $$V'=UVU^{-1}=UVU^\dagger=(-U)V(-U^{-1})=(-U)V(-U^{\dagger})$$
while looking at the $\xi$ transformation $\xi'=U\xi\neq -U\xi=\xi''$ and
looking at the coefficients of $M$ it's evident that is a double cover because are quadratic in $a$ and $b$

Thus, $M=\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} a^2+{a^*}^2-b^2-{b^*}^2 & -i(a^2-{a^*}^2+b^2-{b^*}^2) & -2(ab+a^*b^*) \\\ i(a^2-{a^*}^2-b^2+{b^*}^2) & a^2+{a^*}^2+b^2+{b^*}^2 & -2i(ab-a^*b^*)  \\\ 2(ab^*+a^*b) & 2i(a^*b-ab^*) & 2(|a|^2-|b|^2) \end{pmatrix}$

Addendum:
The matrix $-H$ is defined as$$ \begin{pmatrix} \xi_1  \\\ \xi_2 \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} -\xi_2  & \xi_1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -\xi_1\xi_2 & \xi_1^2 \\\ -\xi_2^2 & \xi_1\xi_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -\xi_1\xi_2 & \xi_1^2 \\\ -\xi_2^2 & \xi_1\xi_2\end{pmatrix}$$
The matrices $-H$ and $\xi\xi^\dagger=\begin{pmatrix} |\xi_1|^2 & \xi_1\xi_2^* \\\ \xi_2\xi_1^* & |\xi_2|^2\end{pmatrix}$ and $V$ transform in the same way under $U(2)$:
$$\xi\xi^\dagger\longrightarrow U(\xi\xi^\dagger)U^\dagger$$
$$\pm H\longrightarrow U(\pm H)U^\dagger$$
$$V\longrightarrow U(V)U^\dagger$$

Comment: What do you mean by "the generic Hermitian traceless matrix transforms by $-H$"?

Comment: That $V$, that is the generic hermitian and traceless matrix, transforms as $-H$. In particular the matrices $-H$ and $\xi\xi^\dagger=\begin{pmatrix} |\xi_1|^2 & \xi_1\xi_2^* \\\ \xi_2\xi_1^* & |\xi_2|^2\end{pmatrix}$ and $V$ transform in the same way under $U(2)$:
$$\xi\xi^\dagger\longrightarrow U(\xi\xi^\dagger)U^\dagger$$
$$\pm H\longrightarrow U(\pm H)U^\dagger$$
$$V\longrightarrow U(V)U^\dagger$$